# Latex: index of symbols

Tags: latex

I want to create an index of symbols or notation, similar to the usual index one obtains with makeindex. I have gotten this to work, using the glossaries package. However, just as in the usual index, I would like to get two columns in the index of symbols, while glossaries puts everything under each other.
Commands like twocolumn or multicol also do not work, because then the second column starts higher than the first, above the title of the index of symbols.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deriving your own style for the glossaries package isn't that difficult.  The trick is going to be not to twocolumn the command you are using to add the index, but to redefine the glossary style to be twocolumn.  The documentation in the glossaries package is pretty good on this.

Update to include explicit realization of my suggestion:

```
\newglossarystyle{wooitspretty}{
    \glossarystyle{list}
    \renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\begin{multicols*}{2}} 
    \renewcommand*{\glossarypostamble}{\end{multicols*}}
}

\printglossary[style=wooitspretty,type=\symboltype]
```

I don't know what type you use, so I left it as a command

Comment: Thanks! I looked through the documentation and found a slightly different approach: \renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\begin{multicols*}{2}}
\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\end{multicols*}}

before \printglossary

Comment: @Daniel: does this approach work for you? If so, vote up McBeth's answer and accept it.

Comment: What you describe is exactly what I suggest, just in a non-scoped manner.  \glossarypreamble and \glossarypostamble are part of the glossary style, if you wrap it in a style, then you don't have to worry about undoing your changes if you add another glossary that needs to look different later